# Formal definition of little-o

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, definition

Here is the definition of little-o:
Let f(n) and g(n) be functions that map positive integers to positive real
numbers. We say that f(n) is o(g(n)) (or f(n) ∈ o(g(n))) if for any real constant c > 0, there exists an
integer constant n0 ≥ 1 such that f(n) < c ∗ g(n) for every integer n ≥ n0.[source](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs345/summer14/files/bigO.pdf)

All the definitions that don't contain limit kind of definition for little-o maps from positive integers to real numbers. The domain is positive and integer. Thus I can not think of any little-o notation when x goes to a finite real number. Because, as the definition of limit for sequences, in order to be as close as to a number it has to go to infinity in integer domain.
However I see questions regarding little-o notations when x goes to a finite number.
Here is my question:
How do we need a definition of little-o so that it can map from real numbers to real numbers?
Here is my attempt:

$ \forall \epsilon > 0 (\exists \delta > 0 (\forall x \in R | (0 < |x-c| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x)| \leq \epsilon * |g(x)| ))) $

Is it okay? If not, what is the correct one?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You will write $f(x)=o(g(x)) (x\to c)$.

Comment: I agree, although the context (i.e. $x\to c$) is generally implicit and does not appear in the notation, we just write $f(x)=o(g(x))$.

Comment: Rem: basically the notation means $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$, the formal way is $|f(x)|<\epsilon|g(x)|$ mainly to get rid of the division by $0$ issue, else this is just re-transcription of the limit definition.

Comment: Can I use my attempt to prove some theorems when I see little-o notation when x goes to a finite number?